# Как правильно экранировать строку?

Tags: c#, экранирование, escape

```
var fromUnixTime="123";
var toUnixTime="123";

var sqlquery = @"
SELECT player.id,
    TO_TIMESTAMP(player.""createTime"")::DATE as ""Дата регистрации"",
    TO_TIMESTAMP(payment.""createTime"")::DATE as ""Дата платежа"",
    payment.""currencyAmount"" as ""Бабки"",
    TO_TIMESTAMP(payment.""rollbackTime"")::DATE as ""Дата возврата бабок""
FROM player
    LEFT JOIN payment ON payment.""playerId"" = player.id
WHERE payment.""currencyAmount"" <> 0 AND 
    (player.""createTime"" >= "+fromUnixTime+" AND player.""createTime"" <= " + toUnixTime+")";
```

Система ругается на последную строку. Подскажите в чем проблема

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы забыли поставить символ `@` перед строкой. Исправьте так:

```
... +fromUnixTime+@" AND player.""createTime"" <= " + toUnixTime+")";
```

либо так:

```
... +fromUnixTime+" AND player.\"\"createTime\"\" <= " + toUnixTime+")";
```

Comment: там наверн обратный слэш :с

Comment: @Buka Верно. Опечатка.

Comment: Символ `@` перед строковым литералом отключает escape-последовательности. Двойные кавычки распознаются как одинарные. После разрыва литерала оператором `+` нужно снова поставить `@`, чтобы всё было "как раньше".